# Microsoft Active Accessibility and UI Automation

Tags: accessibility

Thank you in advance for your possible returns.

My problem is: I use an authentication tool that normally uses the Windows Accessibility API (Microsoft Active Accessibility and UI Automation) to detect open windows (applications) on a workstation, which allows the tool to initiate an authentication request. Basically the tool is based on the API, retrieves all open windows (applications), checks the access rights to the application, then starts or not an authentication request.

However on some computers the detection is not effective, my question is the following: are there ways to check the status of Windows accessibility (UI Automation & Microsoft Active Accessibility) on a computer? Basically it will allow me to make sure that the post in question has no concern for Windows accessibility (or not)

So is there a way to write a program that will check the status of Windows accessibility?

Thanks again for your feedback